# DNN 2sxc Razor template - if user is authenticated

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

In 2SXC, I have a content type and a razor template. In the template, I want to show some content if the user is unauthenticated (not logged in) and then show something else if they are. How would I write this if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    you're logged in
}
else {
    you're not logged in
}
```

Comment: I'll add this to the snippets :)